# How to process Queued WCF Web service requests

Tags: wcf

I have a requirement to Queue web service requests and then process each request based on priority and request time. And then send response back.

The approach I'm thinking is as follows
1 Create a web service method to submit requests and enqueue requests.

2 Create  two queues (high priority requests and lower priority requests)

3 Create a Processing method to process each request one at a time(dequeue the high priority queues first if it exists) process and then store the response

4 Create a dictionary to store response for the respective request.
5 create a web service method to get the response

I'm thinking to use in memory queue since I expect few number of requests queued at a time.

The problem I'm having is in step 3. I want the processor method to continuously run as long as there are requests in the queue.

How can I accomplish step 3 using WCF web service ? 
I'm using .NET 4.0 environment.
I really appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would create my service contract to make it clear that the operations will be queued. Something like:

```
[OperationContract]
string EnqueueRequest(int priority, RequestDetails details);

[OperationContract]
bool IsRequestComplete(string requestId);
```

I would have EnqueueRequest place each request into an MSMQ queue. I'd have a Windows Service processing the requests in the queue. That service would be the only process that has access to the SDLC device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you coded the service in a plane jane, meat and potatoes way and profiled to see if it's necessary to queue requests?  There is overhead involved in queuing.  It's a good idea to do some measurement and see if just servicing requests is adequate.

Another way to approach it would be to use [Microsoft Message Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here is even some tight integration between [message queues and WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx).  The thought is, if you do actually need a queue, why not use something that is already built and tested.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use queue is because the actual processing of the request will be done by external interface that only handles one request at a time (it is SDLC point to point link to IBM 3270 diplay)

Comment: I will take a look at MSMQ and WCF integration. That could solve my issue. Thanks.